# MySQL: Compare date strings?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column which is a string, it holds values like that: `11.05.2012 05:22:12`

Now I want to get all rows that have a `date <= 30.09.2011` in that column. I tried

```
DATE_FORMAT(my_column_with_the_string_date, "%Y-%m-%d") <= '2011-09-30'
```

but this failed (returns no results). Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you need is the `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

```
SELECT
*
FROM yourTable
WHERE
STR_TO_DATE(my_column_with_the_string_date, '%d.%m.%Y') <= '2011-09-30'
```

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: this is not the best for performance, because you make a conversion on all cell from my_column_with_the_string_date.On big table it will be very low.
You should convert the string instead

Comment: We have a range comparison here. You will get false results when comparing strings and not dates.

Comment: @Reign.85 how to convert a string?

Comment: @Alex78191 replace caracters to get SQL date format and then alter the table structure string -> date