# Using formatted String as Date in SQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, string, hibernate, date

Before putting a date in a sql query, I format and convert this date to a String because the java.util.Date doesn't work.

```
//create the date format
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

//convert the date to a String   
String dateString = sdf.format(Date);
```

Then I use the datestring in a sql query in my java code:

```
... +" and (t.actualEndDateTime > '" + dateString + "';
```

I know that java.sql.Date is also an option, but I was just wondering if this is acceptable or a bad practice?

I use Hibernate 3.0 to connect to mySQL db.

Comment: You are using plain jdbc?. Kindly brief DAO Code.

Comment: Not using parameterised queries is certainly bad practice.

Comment: Is this really a SQL query or are you using HQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using *MYSQL* syntax. Check this thread: [MySQL: Compare date strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005992/mysql-compare-date-strings)

But this is not recommended for at least two reasons:

- Using Hibernate, you should prefer *HQL* in order for your app to be
  database agnostic.
- Converting `Date` to `String` for comparison purposes is unnecessary step(only if your dates are stored as strings in db)

Hibernate is able to compare `java.util.Date` correctly with database specific *Date* types